# How to use Python's Error Functionality?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-3.3

Is there a way I can use Python's error functionality to add to my program, as if it were a part of the program. 
So for example, if Python generates an error, the execute this code.

Comment: Did you mean to add in code?  Please show use what you want to execute on an error.  BTW, in Python, they are called exceptions, not errors.

Comment: What do you mean "as if it were a part of the program"?

Comment: @SethMMorton I meant for example, when python runs this function(let's say day_number), and the function takes 2 inputs, and the user only gives 2, so then Python would throw an error. Instead of an error, can't I say if Python throws and error then print to the user to add 3 inputs. I know how to do this using if and else statements, but I want to specifically use the exceptions functionality.Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @kindall I meant when you run a program and it throws and error, the error stops the program, but if it were a part of the program, if would just be like a Boolean value. if it throw an error then do this....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python `try` and `except` statements allow you to do this.

A basic example would be taking input from a user where it has to be an integer value. Using the following code:

```
>>> num = input('Enter a number: ')
Enter a number: f
```

When using the `input` function in Python, it expects an integer value to be entered or a variable or function already defined in your program. (Assume that here, f is not defined in the program). If anything other than an integer or variable/function is entered, the following error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'f' is not defined
```

This example is in interactive mode, but if you had it running in a program instead, the error would occur and the program would be terminated.

`Try` and `except` fix that problem.

**Example**

*Try* input:

```
try:
    num = input('Enter a number: ')
```

Now add the exception:

```
try:
    num = input('Enter a number: ')
except:
    print 'input must be a number or already defined in the program'
    # do something else
```

In this example, Python tries to execute the `input` function, and if no errors occur, it passes the except statement and moves on. If an error occurs however, the exception is executed.

Exceptions can also include the actual error itself, so you can add different events for different errors that could arise.

> > [More information](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html)

Comment: Thank you all for your answer. I appreciate all of your suggestions. You are all awesome.

Comment: A nice illustration of `try ... except` but you give some bad advice. It is not a good idea to use a catch-all `except`: it will forgive everything, including undefined variables and other programmer errors-- you want to trap the user's errors only.

Comment: Also, using `input` to type-check a number is just dumb. `input` accepts any valid python statement (on python 2), not just numbers and variable names. The user can enter *anything,* including `"hello there"` (with the quotes) or `os.system("rm -rf /")`. Always use `raw_input` and check for correctness on your own!

Comment: @alexis thanks for adding that comment. This was just an example and I didn't mean to imply it as real-world. Just the simplest example I could think of. Thanks for adding that clarification

Answer (score 3):

It's called the `try ... except` structure. If you get an error, the stuff under the `except` block gets executed. Read all about it in [the python tutorial.](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html)

```
try:
    print 1/0
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print "Don't do that."
```

Comment: good answer. I'll try this,but still open for more answer.